# Rails production: Google font imported is not loaded

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, import, ruby-on-rails-4.2

### Problem:

After seeing questions about this topic, I request your help.

/assets/stylesheets/styles.css:
`@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather");`

When I run `rails s` on *test* or *development*, the font 'Merriweather' is loaded, but when I run server on *production*, the font is not loaded, but the styles.css is loaded.

---

### What I've tried:

• To put `@import url(...)` in *application.css* or *welcome.scss* or *bootstrap.css.scss*

• To change `@import url('http://fonts.google...')` by `@import url('//fonts.google...')`

### Aditional info:

application.css

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require 'styles'
```

Github:
https://github.com/David-Amrani-Hernandez/MovieReader

Comment: Your website is running on `https` protocol ?

Comment: @NomanUrRehman Nope, is running on http. I'm using Thin, and i'm starting with Rails.

Comment: Try running this command at your project root and then check if it works. I think you are not pre-compiling your assets `rake assets:precompile`

Comment: It does not work. The problem is not that styles.css is not loaded. The problema is the styles.css is loaded but not the font imported. @NomanUrRehman

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried linking directly to the font source in the `<head>` of your application layout file rather than via a stylesheet?

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
    ...
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag( 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather' ) %>
    ...
</head>
```

I have used this method in production several times, and it hasn't given me problems. I hope it is the same for you.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution from @februaryInk works, you can also put `@import url(...)` in application.css.scss. But the other scss files didn't work for me.

Does anyone have an explanation for this somewhat strange behavior? The import statement is in the compiled application-<hash>.css, but the browser just ignores it.